# Trouble - IIS suddenly high memory usage

Tags: performance, iis, memory, performance-monitor

What happens is that a web service on my IIS server significantly increases the ram used.
It works in the range of 200 ~ 700 mb. But for a few days now, he suddenly starts using 3, 4, 5 gb of ram.
As a palliative solution to not block users, I end the service by the task manager itself and it goes back to normal, but some time later it increases again:
[task manager photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcWhq.jpg)

I used the performance monitor and saw that it increases this part here:
[performance monitor photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BPpk.jpg)

I really don't know how to solve this, I'm stuck, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons that your IIS worker process could be using a lot of CPU, to start, you should look at which web requests are currently executing with IIS to see if that helps you identify the issue to be able to troubleshoot IIS worker process.

**Via the IIS Worker Processes**

Via the IIS management console, you can view the running worker processes. You can view which IIS application pool is causing high CPU and view the currently running web requests. after selecting "Worker Processes" from the main IIS menu, you can see the currently running IIS worker processes. If you double-click on a worker process, you can see all of the currently executing requests.